OpenLDAP Read access to users in a group for a certain DN
I want to implement an OTP service (privacyIDEA) with LDAP as backend.
The service needs access to user entries in the LDAP tree. I would like to restrict the access of the service account only to users that belong to a "otp" group.
Meanwhile I read a lot of articles and tutorials on LDAP but I cannot figure out how to achieve this.
Approach 1: groupOfNames
I have the users in ou=users,dc=example,dc=com and a user cn=testuser,ou=users,dc=example,dc=lan (with uid, gid, sn, ...)
I created a group ou=services,dc=example,dc=com and in it cn=otpService,ou=services,dc=example,dc=com
I added a groupOfNames cn=otpService,ou=groupOfNames,dc=example,dc=lan having 'testuser' as member.
But how to set the ACL right? There seems to be no way to filter the access to clause by group membership?!
Approach 2: memberof
Apparently, there is the possibility to have an attribute 'memberof' in the user entry that can be used to filter. However, this feature has allegedly problems with replication and is deprecated.
Approach 3: Custom schema
The alternative I read about is to create my own schema that has an attribute 'enableOTP' in it. Here ACLs would have to be filtered by this attribute.
However, I would like to stick to standards without my own schema modifications.
Is restricting the access the way I want it over-enginieered?
What is a best practice to setup service access to users?
